# bufferedReader.readLine does not work within IF in Android

Tags: java, android, io, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am writing Android. The app should read line of a file from web, and shows the message on the textView. I use bufferedReader. It works fine when I have bufferedReader.readLine() inside a while loop. But it does not work when I have it in a IF statement (shows nothing, although there's something I see in debug mode).

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.tc.umn.edu/~yang4131/jtest.json");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(code==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){ // 200

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                if (in != null) {

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";


                    /*
                    if((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                    if((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                    if((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                    */

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;

                }
                in.close();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result; // this return statement is needed, no matter what
    }
```

I replicated this thing in pure Java in Eclipse, with a local file. It works fine. I really have no idea.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that in an if statement? Are you sure it's not just reading an empty line?

Comment: @Natecat I'm sure none of first three lines are empty lines. I know this does not make much sense but it seems so odd to me.

Comment: Hard to believe. Impossible actually. NB `in` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it. Don't write pointless tests.

Comment: @EJP you're right on this. I didn't realize this had nothing to do with the logic but the View part - my textView is partially blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Adding `result += "\n\n\n\n";` after the concatenation will make the content appear. I think this has something to do with UI, perhaps my textView is blocked for few lines or whatnot.